# Predicting the impact point of a moving object

Tags: machine-learning, estimation, prediction, kalman-filter

Suppose we have a moving object (a horizontal projectile motion as one of the most basic examples). Is there any way to predict where it will hit finally? Please note that I'm looking for a machine learning method not a closed form solution.

Although we can track the motion, using Kalman filter, that is only applicable when we want to predict the new future*(As far as I'm considered)*. But I need to predict the ultimate goal of a moving object.

To better express the problem let see the following example:

Suppose a goalkeeper robot that of course uses filtering methods to smooth the ball motion. It needs to predict if the ball is going to enter the goal or not, before it decide to catch the ball or neglect it to go out.

Thanks for any help

Comment: You might be able to ask a better question.  You are asking yes/no is it in the goal.  That is a binary question, and doesn't pre-stage you for the next step.  You can ask questions so that the answer for step one also answers step 2.  What is the location that it crosses the plane of the goal?  If your KF gives you a best estimate of that then not only do you know IF it is a goal, but you know where you should put your goalie.

Answer (score 1):

How is the problem any different from simply projecting a particle (i.e. the state) through space and time based on current position and momenta? In the case of the Kalman filter, you just do one more thing - you project the error covariance of the projected state as well.

Comment: As you mentioned correctly, I should use a filter to estimate the future state of the target considering both the ideal dynamic model and error. The only thing that I still can't understand is that how should I use the corrected model to predict the position of the object after a long time?

Comment: It is confusing because the state model only shows the state of the target in the next subsequent period. In [https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/login.jsp?tp=&arnumber=1595579&url=http%3A%2F%2Fieeexplore.ieee.org%2Fiel5%2F10633%2F33567%2F01595579.pdf%3Farnumber%3D1595579] it illustrated the need to propagate the state, forward to the time that the target is assumed to strike the ground.
Could you possibly explain me what does it mean to **propagate the state forward**?